# Apollo client, merges objects when 'id' propery is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client, react-apollo

Hi i m quering some data from apollo server with the below structure:

```
       hero {
        image {
          id
          name
          mimeType
          url
        }
        title
        description
      }
      welcome {
        image {
          id
          name
          mimeType
          url
        }
        title
        description
     }
```

**The data that i receive in the 'response' (in browser dev tools) is like below:**

---

```
     hero {
        image {
          "id": ''
          "name": ''
          "mimeType": ''
          "url": ''
          "__typename":"Asset"
        }
        title: 'some title'
        description: 'some description'
        "__typename":"Hero"
      }
      welcome {
        image {
          "id": ''
          "name": ''
          "mimeType": ''
          "url": 'intro/welcome.png'
          "__typename":"Asset"
        }
        title: 'another title'
        description: 'another description'
        "__typename":"Welcome"
     }
```

But when i `console.log` the returned data, into the code, i get merged 'image' object, like so:

```
       hero {
        image {
          "id": '',
          "name": '',
          "mimeType": '',
          "url": 'intro/welcome.png',        <-- welcome.image.url merged here as well.
        }
        title: 'some title',
        description: 'some description',
      }
      welcome {
        image {
          "id": '',
          "name": '',
          "mimeType": '',
          "url": 'intro/welcome.png',
        }
        title: 'another title',
        description: 'another description',
     }
```

**Questions:**

So, based on the above i want to understand what is the reason behind this happening. Is it a rule that i have to enable/disable ? is it a principle that states, 'when there is no **id** value, i merge the objects' ?

I read in the docs that Apollo client makes unique keys based on `id + typename`, so in this case, is it confused ? (I concluded that the 'id' must have value always.)

And on the other hand, what is gonna happen if the 'ids' have the same value ?

I attach the source that i consult, for reference: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-field-behavior/#the-merge-function

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`''` is still a string, and as such a valid identifier, such as `'5'` or `'foo'`.

Apollo Client assumes that if two elements have the same `__typename` and `id`, they are the same object and should be merged together.

"No id" would mean that either you don't request the `id` field, or it would come back as `null` - and in those cases, they would not get merged.

You can override this behaviour by providing your own [`dataIdFromObject`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#dataidfromobject) function - but if you have control over your backend, it would probably better to have it return `null` in these cases.

Comment: yeah, makes sense.   It sees 'hero.image.id' === 'welcome.image.id' and the so `__typename` and it merges them. Thanks.  But in the same way, what is gonna happen if the 'id's are the same on these 2 objects ? I guess although they have same 'id' if they have different 'url' they should not be merged in any way.

Comment: If they have the same `id`, they should be describing the same object. `id`s are assumed to be globally unique, at least within a Typename.